# Laravel: Redirecting index to another index. Call a route from a route or controller?

Tags: laravel

I have a bunch of routes defined

```
# Programs Management
Route::resource('programs', 'AdminProgramController');

Route::resource('scheduled_programs', 'AdminScheduledProgramController');

Route::resource('attendees', 'AdminAttendeeController');

# User Management
Route::get('users/{user}/show', 'AdminUsersController@getShow');
Route::get('users/{user}/edit', 'AdminUsersController@getEdit');
Route::post('users/{user}/edit', 'AdminUsersController@postEdit');
Route::get('users/{user}/delete', 'AdminUsersController@getDelete');
Route::post('users/{user}/delete', 'AdminUsersController@postDelete');
Route::controller('users', 'AdminUsersController');

# User Role Management
Route::get('roles/{role}/show', 'AdminRolesController@getShow');
Route::get('roles/{role}/edit', 'AdminRolesController@getEdit');
Route::post('roles/{role}/edit', 'AdminRolesController@postEdit');
Route::get('roles/{role}/delete', 'AdminRolesController@getDelete');
Route::post('roles/{role}/delete', 'AdminRolesController@postDelete');
Route::controller('roles', 'AdminRolesController');

# Admin Dashboard
Route::controller('/', 'AdminDashboardController');
```

Looks nice and neat to me but I know that my `/` route will just point to `scheduled_programs` for now. I might change it later to point to another route but it will probably never need it's own view.

```
class AdminDashboardController extends AdminController {

/**
 * Admin dashboard
 *
 */
public function getIndex()
{
    return View::make('admin/dashboard');
}



class AdminScheduledProgramController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of scheduled_programs
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $programs = ScheduledProgram::all();

        return View::make('admin/scheduled_programs/index', compact('programs'));
    }
```

I am new to the framework, where does it make sense to change the route, in the route or the Controller? How do I do that? IE call a route from a route or a controller? I assume it would be bad form to just copy the index code from one to the other. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opps, answer was obvious, just return Redirect::route to the other route.

```
class AdminDashboardController extends AdminController {

    /**
     * Admin dashboard
     *
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return Redirect::route('admin.scheduled_programs.index');
    }

}
```